# Powershell - How to get index columns for a given list

Tags: indexed-column

For some strange reasons I can't get to the Index page. It gives me following error. Is there a way to get the index columns via powershell?

http://local.intranet.net/sales/_layouts/IndexedColumns.aspx?List=%7B4E92D288-DC09-4764-B822-7BAD932C3C79%7D

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is the Pwershell code to get indexed column names:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity http://aissp2013/sites/team
$list = $web.Lists["Employees"]
foreach ($field in $list.Fields)
{
    if ($field.Indexable)
    {
        if ($field.Indexed)
        {   
            Write-Host $field.Title     
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nadeem: I worked like charmed. I was able to find the troubled Index columns and used SharePoint Manager 2010 to set the index to false. It turned out I had 2 Expiration Date columns on the same list. But from the UI it only listed one instance of the Expiration Data column. Although, they both had different internal name and Hidden property is set to false. Anyway, the page loads now. and Thank you for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: Btw, I am not a registered user and I lost my session so this forum wont let me mark your reply as answer. If anyone can make Nadeem's post as answer I would appreciate it.

Comment: The only one who can mark an answer is the creator of the question I'm afraid